# Left and right quotation mark render as unexpected character in Safari

Tags: html, text, utf-8, html-entities

I have a simple piece of text like so:

```html
<h1 class="intro-text" id="main-title">&lsquo;AN ABRAM&rsquo;</h1>
```

This should render the following output (this is correct in Google Chrome):

[image: Google Chrome]

But when I open the same file in Safari the output looks like this:

[image: Safari]

Why is this happening and how do I make sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: Bad fix, but does this work: <h1 class="intro-text" id="main-title">&lsquo;&#00;AN ABRAM&#00;&rsquo;</h1>

Comment: Are these browsers on the same machine?

Comment: Do you have a custom font?

Comment: @Rob no happens on difference machines. All of them mac's though.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, but it is happening in all different types of font families...

Comment: @clankill3r no that just adds and white diamond with question mark to the mess :p

Comment: Probably won't help, but did you set the doctype?

Comment: @clankill3r yes i did

Comment: @FutureCake Please expand the snippet, or otherwise create a demo, that enables others with the same setup to see the issue.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I will add a demo link asap.

Comment: @ArnavThorat in the end it just turned out to be a font that had some problems... 
So in this case it was solution 2. 
Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: No worries! I actually thought it was #1. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a few issues of why your text is rendering differently in different browsers.

---

**1. HTML `charset` not set to `utf-8`**

This is a very common solution for your issue. Sometimes, the unexpected character rendering occurs when the `charset` isn't set to `utf-8`.

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset):

> [`charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) - **This attribute declares the document's character encoding.** If the attribute is present, its value must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "`utf-8`", because UTF-8 is the only valid encoding for HTML5 documents. `<meta>` elements which declare a character encoding must be located entirely within the first 1024 bytes of the document.

In short, the `charset` attribute defines the character encoding, and what each character will *"render"* to.

To add this in your HTML, you need to add it in your `<head>`, like so.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="intro-text" id="main-title">&lsquo;AN ABRAM&rsquo;</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

This should state that the encoding of the HTML document should be UTF-8. This way, Safari shouldn't print out the characters in a different way.

*Note: There are known issues of Safari encoding the text differently than Google Chrome, so this solution is most likely the best fix.*

---

**2. Fonts (OP's working solution)**

Another issue that could occur is the fonts that have been chosen to be on the webpage.

Sometimes, fonts can be the reason Safari doesn't render the symbols like normal. This can be for many reasons.

However, to see if fonts are the issue, then you should remove all of the `font-family` specifications in your CSS.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Some-Font"; /* Try and remove this */
}
```

The default font in a HTML document (if it isn't specified) is Times New Roman. If the issue doesn't occur after changing the font, then the issue was the font. In this case, you would need to find another font to be in your HTML document.

---

**3. No `DOCTYPE`**

The third issue in this list is no `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of your HTML.

Even though this solution may not be related to your issue, this is a good thing to try.

If you don't have the `DOCTYPE`, you need to add it in the location specified below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

<sup>Shown on **Line 1**.</sup>

This may help solve the issue.

---

In conclusion, these are the three solutions. They are ranked from most likely to fix, from least likely to fix.

1. HTML `charset` not set to `utf-8`
2. Fonts (OP's working solution)
3. No `DOCTYPE`

These should fix your problem.

Comment: FYI, it's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `"‘AN ABRAM’".encode( 'mac_roman').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `ÔAN ABRAMÕ`.

Comment: @JosefZ interesting, do you know a way apart from the options mentioned by Arnav to fix this issue? Could i recode the font-family manually or do some other magic?

Comment: Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…